# url templatetag with "safe" arguments?

Tags: django-templates

I'm trying to use the `{% url %}` template tag but with an argument to be substituted out later in Javascript.  It looks something like this:

```
var pid = '7a8b323f-52b1-466c-91d3-b4i4d85b1c32';
var status_url = '{% url quote_status form_urlname inquiry_id instance_id '{0}' %}'.format(pid);
```

I tried using both `{% autoescape off %}` and `|safe`, neither of which seemed to work.  Is there a good way to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

(snip previous answer, sorry, didn't read carefully enough)

If the argument is required to build the url, it just won't work - the templatetag is executed on the server, the javascript is executed on the browser.